# Piecewise function inside ProbabilityDistribution causing errors

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, random, piecewise

I'm using a complicated Piecewise function to create a probability distribution and draw random points from it.

```
rule1 := {
  a1 -> 1.,
  a2 -> 5.,
  y1 -> 1.4,
  z1 -> 4.83,
  xmin -> 3.,
  xmax -> 87.,
  b -> 0.4
  }

rule2 := {xbreak -> xmin + b*(xmax - xmin)} /. rule1

f[x_, z1_] := z1/x - z1/(x - z1)

S[x_, xmin_, z1_] := (Exp[f[x - xmin, z1]] + 1)^-1

func[x1_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(x1^-a1)*S[x1, xmin, z1], (x1 > xmin) && (x1 < xbreak)}, {(x1^-a2)*S[x1, xmin, z1], (x1 > xbreak) && (x1 < xmax)}}]

distfunc = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[func[x] /. rule1 /. rule2, {x, 5, 200}, 
   Method -> "Normalize"];

RandomVariate[distfunc]
```

When I do RandomVariate it is causing all kinds of errors including

```
SparseArray::bndstd: The starting position {1,3} for the band Band[{1,3}] is not an explicit element position in an array with dimensions {1,1}.

Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0,{1,{{0,1},{{1}}},{LinearSolve[SparseArray[{Band[<<1>>]->{<<1>>},Band[<<1>>]->{}},{1,1}]][SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0.,{1,{{0,1},{{1}}},{1.}}]]}}] cannot be transposed.

ArrayPad::arr: First argument Transpose[SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0,{1,{{0,1},{{1}}},{LinearSolve[SparseArray[{Rule[<<2>>],Rule[<<2>>]},{1,1}]][SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0.,{1,{<<2>>},{1.}}]]}}]] to ArrayPad should be an array.

Drop::drop: Cannot drop positions -2 through -1 in Transpose[SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0,{1,{{0,1},{{1}}},{LinearSolve[SparseArray[{Rule[<<2>>],Rule[<<2>>]},{1,1}]][SparseArray[Automatic,{1},0.,{1,{<<2>>},{1.}}]]}}]].

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Join::heads: Heads Times and SparseArray at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.

Interpolation::inhr: Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {0}.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  Your code works fine for 12.1  and 12.0 (Windows 10).

Comment: I'm using 12.0 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually I haven't used the actual values of constants in rules. When I use z1 -> 4.83 then it is causing errors. It seems to be working with z1 -> 4. but not with 4.83. Why is that?

Comment: I think the problem is that when using `z1->4.83` there is a discontinuity in the pdf around `x=7.93` and *Mathematica* doesn't handle that well.  If when `z1->4.83` the minimum x value is changed from 5 to 8, then everything works fine.